# How to produce a sequence of parallel XML elements (STag content ETag) using its grammar?

Tags: xml, parsing, syntax, context-free-grammar

I refer to [this link](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-content) for the following grammar,

```
[1]  document      ::=      prolog element Misc*
[39] element       ::=      STag content ETag
[43] content       ::=      CharData? ((element | Reference | CDSect | PI | Comment) CharData?)*
```

Obviously, we can produce elements (like, `<p>hello world</p>`) by decomposing

- `element` to `<p> content </p>`, and then
- `content` to `hello world`

But, what I am wondering is how to produce a sequence of parallel elements, like below,

```
<p>hello world</p>
<p>hello world</p>
<p>hello world</p>
<p>hello world</p>
```

It seems that we can only decompose the `element` in the grammar into nested elements, like below,

```
<p>
   <p>
       <p>hello world</p>
   </p>
</p>
```

From what I understand, in order to produce a sequence of parallel elements, we need to use a grammar like the following one,

```
document      ::=      prolog elements Misc*
elements      ::=      STag content ETag (STag content ETag)*
content       ::=      CharData? ((element | Reference | CDSect | PI | Comment) CharData?)*
```

So, did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked grammar says that:

- a `document` must have a single top-level `element`, and
- an `element` (via `content`) can contain zero or more (child) `element`s.

So,

```
<p>hello world</p>
<p>hello world</p>
```

isn't a well-formed document, but

```
<something>
  <p>hello world</p>
  <p>hello world</p>
</something>
```

*is* a well-formed document.

---

Your suggested grammar would allow

```
<p>hello world</p>
<p>hello world</p>
```

as a `document` (well, not quite, because it doesn't allow the line-break between the two elements), but then you're not talking about XML documents any more.